# How to respond to view lifecycle events in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How to respond to view lifecycle events in SwiftUI?

```
onAppear()
onDisappear()
```

XCode Version: 12.0

Comment: Hello kinder ,can you take a look to this blog post : 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear

Answer (score 3):

Like this way :

```
VStack {
   Text("Hello World") 
}.onAppear {
    print("ContentView appeared!")
}.onDisappear {
    print("ContentView disappeared!")
}
```